# Profiling tesseract-ocr with GNU gprof

Tags: c++, c, gnu, tesseract, gprof

I am trying to profile tesseract-ocr with GNU gprof. After modifying the Makefile to add "-pg" to CFLAGS, I make/make install the program and then execute an OCR command. At this point, I'm expecting to see a generated "gmon.out" file somewhere, but nothing is being generated.

I have never used GNU gprof before. Am I missing something? Here is what I did, on a high level:

1. compiled and installed Leptonica (a dependency for tesseract-ocr)
2. ./configure on tesseract-ocr, and then added "-pg" to CFLAGS in the Makefile
3. make, make install on tesseract-ocr
4. Run an OCR command (tesseract /home/me/test.jpg ocr_out.txt -spa)

I have also tried to add "-pg" to other variables such as CXX and LDFLAGS. I tried this in the Makefile for both tesseract-ocr and Leptonica.

**I should also note that I'm doing this all on cygwin...**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the FLAGS in "config.status" which autoconfigurates the makefiles of all the applications in tesseract-ocr.

Add -pg to CFLAGS,CXXFLAGS, and CPPFLAGS and then tell me how it works.

Coincedentally, I'm also trying to profile tesseract with gnu gprof, except in my gmon.out I'm seeing that there is only one function in the call stack with 0s. I'd like to know if your result is any different, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding -pg to CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, and CPPFLAGS in config.status did indeed generate a gmon.out. I'm seeing the same thing as you though - only one function (_GLOBAL__sub_I_main) in the call stack with 0s. Hm. I'm going to try and look into this. Please let me know if you find anything. Would it be necessary to add -pg to the leptonica build, also?

Comment: Here's an update. I was able to generate a gmon.out containing 1721 functions. In my original post, I mentioned that I was doing everything on Cygwin. Well, yesterday when I tried your recommendation to add -pg to config.status, I did that on another (Ubuntu) linux environment. Today, I tried it on my original Cygwin environment, and it worked. Aside from environment, I did not do anything differently...